# Spring-data 2.1 get "UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property" with kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Environment:
Spring-boot 2.1.2.RELEASE,
Spring-data 2.1.4.RELEASE,
Kotlin 1.2.x ~ 1.3.x,
Mongodb.

I defined a model class like:

```
@Document
class MeAccount : Setting() {

    lateinit var id: String

    val accountEntries = listOf<BankAccount>()
 }
```

When I tried to read this model from mongodb, I got exception stacktrace blow:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property private final java.util.List com.xxx.MeCustodianAccount.accountEntries!
    at com.xxx.MeCustodianAccount_Accessor_fs514j.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:378)
```

For attention, the code works fine with spring-boot 1.5.x and spring-data 1.x.

What can I do to solve this issue? 
Seems many similar exception reports below:

[Spring boot 2.1.0 security change with kotlin data class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214153/spring-boot-2-1-0-security-change-with-kotlin-data-class)

https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/issues/123

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15698

**[Resolved] Works after fall back to Spring-boot 2.0.x and spring-data-commons 2.0.x.** Will keep 2.1 excluded in future upgrading plans.

Comment: `val` properties don’t have a setter. Change it to `var`

Comment: @Strelok that is totally unacceptable, val is my admirable feature from kotlin. And the code works with spring-data 1.12.x.

Comment: Welp, sorry, but that's a fact. Vals in the body need to be initialized in the init block, constructor, or or inline. They don't have a setter

Comment: Have you considered making this a `data` class and moving the properties into the constructor? As you have it now, nothing (including Spring Data MongoDB) can ever set the value for `accountEntries`.

Comment: As I said, the 'val' is the most wanted feature of kotlin for us, and the code failed because spring-data 2.1.x breaks the compatiblility. @Mark B The code works totally fine in former spring-data releases.

Comment: @JackZhu sounds like you need to file a bug report with Spring Data then if this works with a previous version.

Answer (score 11):

Spring Data in 2.1. has changed the way in which it deals with final fields in entities. It no longer uses reflection to override the immutability of the fields, which in general is good. There are a few ways to cope with the problem.

They are described here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1374?focusedCommentId=182289&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-182289

Here's what the Spring guys recommend:

> 1. Add a @PersistenceConstructor to construct the entity that sets immutable fields.
> 2. Add wither methods (MyEntity withXxx(…)) to create a new instance that contains the changed property value.
> 3. Alternatively: Use Kotlin's data class feature. This will basically do the same as wither methods.

So for you should work something like this:

```java
@Document
data class MeAccount(val id: String, val accountEntries: List<Price>) : Setting()
```

Comment: Adding only the `@PersistenceConstructor` results in an error for me. Using Lombok's `@With` (bullet 2) works.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record because I have not found same question about spring data for apache cassandra and the documentation recommendate using only @Value to avoid boilerplate for inmutable variation of @Data on DTOs, but following that example spring throws UnsupportedOperationException, to solve this the dto must have lombok experimental **@Wither** to work.

**Repository**

```
<T> List<T> findByActive(Class<T> class);
```

**DTO**

```
@Value
public class PersonDTO {

    private UUID id;
    private Boolean active;
}
```

**Test - call**

```
    List<PersonDTO> personList  = personService.findByActive(PersonDTO.class);
```

g

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property private final java.lang.Boolean com.x.dto.PersonDTO.active!
    at com.x.dto.PersonDTO_Accessor_y82uew.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.DtoInstantiatingConverter.lambda$convert$0(DtoInstantiatingConverter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:369)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.DtoInstantiatingConverter.convert(DtoInstantiatingConverter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.lambda$and$0(ResultProcessor.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$ResultProcessingConverter.convert(CassandraQueryExecution.java:267)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:232)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.AbstractCassandraQuery.execute(AbstractCassandraQuery.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.findByActive(Unknown Source)
    at com.x.service.impl.PersonServiceImpl.findByActive(PersonServiceImpl.java:22)
    at com.x.PersonRepositoryTest.findByActive(PersonRepositoryTest.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

[Spring Data for Apache Cassandra - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic)

> Avoid boilerplate code for projection DTOs You can dramatically
>   simplify the code for a DTO by using Project Lombok, which provides an
>   @Value annotation (not to be confused with Spring’s @Value annotation
>   shown in the earlier interface examples). If you use Project Lombok’s
>   @Value annotation, the sample DTO shown earlier would become the
>   following:

```
@Value
@Wither //added - not included in documentation
class NamesOnly {
    String firstname, lastname;
}
```

> Dynamic Projections So far, we have used the projection type as the
>   return type or element type of a collection. However, you might want
>   to select the type to be used at invocation time (which makes it
>   dynamic). To apply dynamic projections, use a query method such as the
>   one shown in the following example:
>
> **Example 86. A repository using a dynamic projection parameter**

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, UUID> {

  <T> Collection<T> findByLastname(String lastname, Class<T> type);
}
```